# How to select a specific element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** some profile informations on linkedIn. I came across an html structure with this kind of layout and need to select this "Abeokuta, Ogun State" only and disregard "Contract".

This is a page sample: https://www.linkedin.com/in/habibulah-oyero-44069a193/

html structure

```
<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Abeokuta, Ogun State
      <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Contract</span>
</p>
```

python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

experience_div = soup.find("section", {"id": "experience-section"})

job_div = experience_div.find("div", {"class": "pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section"})

job_location = job_div.find("p", {"class": "pv-entity__secondary-title"}).text.strip()

print(job_location)

This returns:

Abeokuta, Ogun State
        Contract
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get the first tag, you can use the [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method which will *only* return the *first* match:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Abeokuta, Ogun State
      <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Contract</span>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.find("p", class_="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal")
    .find_next(text=True)
    .strip()
)
```

Or: You can use [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
print(
    soup.find("p", class_="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal")
    .contents[0]
    .strip()
)
```

Output (in both solutions):

```
Abeokuta, Ogun State
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. how about getting the second element content. I tried "print(
    soup.find("p", class_="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal")
    .contents[1]
    .strip()
)" but it gave an error.

Comment: @king_bibah First use `.text` and then `.strip()`:   `.contents[1].text.strip()`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.

Comment: something seems confusing here. I will be really glad if you could explain. using "soup.find("p", class_="appropriate_class").contents[1].text.strip()" returns the second item which is "Contract" but using "soup.find("p", class_="appropriate_class").contents[0].text.strip()" doesn't return the first item. While using "soup.find("p", class_="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal") .contents[0].strip()" returns the first object.